# My heroku cedar app is using varnish without my permission

Tags: django, heroku, varnish

The Heroku docs say that cedar apps do not use varnish, but I can clearly see the http headers of my app bandtastic.me (a django app) with varnish data. I am trying to debug an error but the request does not even hit my app so I can't.

How can I disable varnish for my app? I do not want it, specially because of this bug it's causing.

The bug triggers in some cases where I POST to the current url, so I smell varnish trying to use the cache as a response but this obviously fails and I get a generic heroku app error.
The logs are clear, my debug logger gets nothing, so it's not even hitting my app.

I got these addons:

- Heroku Postgres
- MemCachier
- PG Backups
- Redis To Go
- Shared Database
- Zerigo DNS

Are any of these forced with Varnish? Maybe the Zerigo one...

Comment: Are you using any of the SSL features (IP, Hostname etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably cnaming to proxy.heroku.com instead of proxy.herokuapp.com - you may see headers but it is being bypassed.

Comment: Yeah thats correct. The problem is that i have this app mirrored byte by byte on another.herokuapp.com and the bug only shows on the app with the domain cnamed.
And i can't debug it because as i said is not hitting my app, the problem is in between so i thought maybe is varnish.